# Execute shell with custom command

Tags: c#, windows, shell, contextmenu, explorer

I'm just trying to execute a shell command on a Windows 7 machine using C#.

I found this snippet in the web:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "ShellExecute")]
public static extern long ShellExecute(int hwnd, string cmd, string file, string param1, string param2, int swmode);

void exe()
{
    ShellExecute (0, "open", "C:\WINDOWS\Zapotec.bmp", "", "", 5)
}
```

This works very nice, but I don't want to open it, I want to execute a custom command (from a third party application). Concrete: I want to do a virus scan (can be started in the context menu in the windows explorer) with a virus scanner that has no commandline interface.

Any suggestions? I did not find any helpful information in the internet. 
It does not have to be a C# solution. It can also be an external file (I found the program "runmenu" [http://www.programbits.co.uk/downloads/runmenu.zip], which should be perfect for this problem, but unfortunately not all context menu entries are supported).

**UPDATE**

I just found a solution for my problem using powershell:

```
PS C:\temp> $o = new-object -com Shell.Application
PS C:\temp> $folder = $o.NameSpace("C:\temp")
PS C:\temp> $file=$folder.ParseName("test.txt")
PS C:\temp> $file.Verbs() | select Name
PS C:\temp> $file.Verbs() | %{ if($_.Name -eq 'Edit with &Notepad++') { $_.DoIt() } }
```

[enter link description here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/04/26/use-powershell-to-work-with-windows-explorer.aspx)

Comment: Its a bit unclear what you want to do. Can't you just use some gui-automation script like AutoHotKey http://www.autohotkey.com/ or AutoIt http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

private void runCom(string command)
{
    ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c" + command);
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. But how can I just execute a shell command (context menu entry in the windows explorer). Your code just runs an executable with arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use Process.Start()?

You can use the ProcessStartInfo overload to send arguments as required.

Found within the System.Diagnostics namespace.

Answer (score 0):

As Already Suggested by Jason , 
Look in System.Diagnostics Namespace of .NET Framework . It is used to invoke Process .

You can set useShellExecute property of  ProcessStartInfo  to true ; to Suppress Window spawn ,.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `System.Diagnostics.Process` class ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: @user2445254 please do not add new questions into the answers by editing them. Use comments to ask things from the author of the answer.

Comment: Im sorry for that, i wanted to add a comment - lack of concentration ;) sorry.